# invalid integer value "CONNECTION" for connection option "port" Previous connection kept

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12

I'm new to postgres and I'm trying to configure table level logical replication(PUBLICATION/SUBSCRIPTION) on postgres-12.

I have updated postgresql.conf file and updated wal_level=replica. Also, then created 2 databases(test1 and test2). Here is what , I'm doing:

```
test1=# create table t1(a int primary key, b int);
CREATE TABLE
test1=# insert into t1 values(1, 1);
INSERT 0 1
test1=# create publication my_pub for table t1;
CREATE PUBLICATION

test2=# CREATE TABLE t1(a int primary key, b int);
CREATE TABLE
test2=# CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_sub CONNECTION 'host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test2 user=postgres 
password=password' PUBLICATION my_pub;
invalid integer value "CONNECTION" for connection option "port"
Previous connection kept
```

When creating subscription I'm getting this message: invalid integer value "CONNECTION" for connection option "port"
Previous connection kept and I'm unable to add this table into replication. In my postgresql.conf file as well I have mentioned 5432 port only. However, I'm unable to understand why it's saying invalid integer value

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Are test1 and test2 located in the same database instance?

Comment: test1 and test2 belongs to same cluster

Comment: If I run the non-prompt parts of the above with two databases in the same cluster, I very reproducibly get an internal, undetected deadlock.  Just as the docs say you will.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes - I got it working when tried from 2 separate clusters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you really must have done is something like:

```
\c CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_sub CONNECTION ...
```

The arguments to \c are positional, and the 4th position belongs to the port.

I see no other way your message could include 'Previous connection kept', which is exclusively generated by attempts to use \c or \connect

Comment: no @jjanes - I didn't run it with \c. Do you have any other method to make it working for me?

Comment: Maybe you don't *think* you did that, but there is no other way to have gotten that error message.  In the absence of a reproducible test case, I maintain that what you actually did is not what you think you did.